# Convert ImageByteArray to BufferedImage

Tags: java, arrays, byte, bufferedimage

I've checked several examples on how to convert `byte[]` to `BufferedImage`, but I can't seem to get it working. I convert an image to byte array with:

```
        BufferedImage b = null, c=null;
        try {
            b = ImageIO.read(Main.class.getResource("res/lvl/Medieval.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] imageByteArray = ((DataBufferByte) b.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

Then I try to convert it back with:

```
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByteArray);

        try {
            c = ImageIO.read(bais);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

`c` is still `null` after this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the problem is with writing.

Comment: Hmm.. I think your intentions here is a little unclear... Do you want to do manipulations on the raw pixel data? Then you don't need to create a new image from the data, the changes will be reflected to the image. Or do you just want to make a copy of the image?

Comment: If you just want to copy the image, there are easier ways. Also, your assumption that the image is using `DataBufferByte` will of course not be correct for all images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code line

```
byte[] imageByteArray = ((DataBufferByte) b.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

doesn't create a valid byte array for an image.

Use this code instead:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(b, "png", baos);
    byte[] imageByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: I am glad it worked for you - consider to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

What you have after your first conversion is the raw pixel data. Instead of using ImageIO (which can read images in a serialized format), try to do the oposite conversion you did to make the byte array in the first place.

Typically somethig like this:

```
    DataBufferByte buffer = new DataBufferByte(bytes, bytes.length);
    ColorModel cm = new ComponentColorModel(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB), new int[]{8, 8, 8}, false, false, Transparency.OPAQUE, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
    return new BufferedImage(cm, Raster.createInterleavedRaster(buffer, width, height, scanline, bpp, bandOffsets, null), false, null);
```

However, the image will be identical to the first image, so I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve here..?

PS: Be aware that the image byte array is not cloned (unless you do it explicitly), so the images will share pixel data.

Comment: What I want to, is to transform it to byte array so that I can encode it in base64 to send over socket, then reassemble at the other end. So its the exact same image.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is within writing not retrieving the image from the byte code, the image must be wrote pixel by pixel.
I've interested with your short way to convert the image to *byte* array and vise but unfortunately the first fails.
Maybe this method I made for your will help you :

- Create your own class names for example ImageConversation or any name.
- Make all the conversation (byte[] to image or Image to bye[]) static so that you can call them by Class name.

This method will converts the selected file form FileChooser or a given file and convert it to *byte[]*, however it's a little bit long and it couldn't be a the best way, but it gives a nice result and I have no problem with it.

```
        public static byte [] imageToBytoArray(File file){

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray;
        try{
            FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte [] buffer = new byte [1024];
            for(int i ;(i=fileStream.read(buffer)) !=-1;){
                byteArray.write(buffer, 0, i);
            }
            return byteArray.toByteArray();

        }catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```